# can not access e-mail attachment

Tags: iphone

I used the code below to get the email attachment file url.

```
NSURL *url=(NSURL*)[launchOptions valueForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsURLKey];
```

but

```
bool b=[[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExists:[url absoluteString];
```

always returns NO, which means the email attachment file does not exist.

Welcome any comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't you want to use

```
 bool b=[[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExists:[url path];
```

rather than sending the NSURL instance an absoluteString message?

Answer (score 0):

you could not **access/Open** the attachment in your application but you could open **iphone/ipad** email client and add an attachment into.

> Only the file can be accessed in application which are the part of your application sandbox.

Comment: @monsabre : Read it carefully **Download PDF files from Email attachment with our built in browser**. Means When you open the application they will provide `UIWebView` where you could login into your mail account and download the attachment in the **sandbox** of their application. **SO** they are'nt accessing the download from iPhone/iPad build in email client,

Comment: why do you not download and test the app check if it works as I said

Comment: @monsabre : Sure. will check it soon.